# How to call selector in static method implementation

Tags: xcode, static-methods

How can I call selector in static method implementation?

I tried this, but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

WhiteScreenFader.m

```
+(void) fadeIn:(float)duration inView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)selector
{
.
.
.
   [NSObject performSelector:selector]; //??
}
```

ViewController.m

```
//  I call static method like this
[WhiteScreenFader fadeIn:1.0 inView:self.view withAction:@selector(segue:)];
```

--- UPDATE
Here is complete implementation

```
+(void) fadeIn:(float)duration inView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)selector
{
//  bielu uiview
UIView *whiteView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
[whiteView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[whiteView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
whiteView.alpha = 0;
[view addSubview:whiteView];

//  fade to 0
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    whiteView.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [NSObject performSelector:selector];
}];
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do by this?

Comment: @H2CO3 I need to perform some action after animation is complete. Here is complete implementation..please see updated question

Comment: tried `[self performSelector:selector];`?

Comment: `segue` is not a class method on `NSObject`.

Comment: I got warning: PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown. App crashes

Comment: @mipadi segue is my own function...

Comment: @alexhajdu: Is it declared as a class method on `NSObject`?

Comment: @mipadi it's function in view controller : UIViewController

Comment: @alexhajdu: Then you should call `[UIViewController performSelector:selector]` for that. Or, more generally, in `+[WhiteScreenFader fadeIn:inView:withAction]`, you should add a `target` parameter and call `[target performSelector:selector]`.

Comment: @mipadi thanks, going to try it. And my class WhiteScreenFader is NSObject, is that ok?

Comment: @alexhajdu: Well, no, actually. An *instance* of `WhiteScreenFader` is an `NSObject`, but `WhiteScreenFader` itself is a `Class`, which is *not* an `NSObject`.

Comment: @mipadi It works.  I call static function in ViewController:[WhiteScreenFader fadeIn:1.0 inView:self.view withAction:@selector(afterAnimation) andTarget:self]; And implementation is : 
+(void) fadeIn:(float)duration inView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)selector andTarget:(id)target
{
...
 [target performSelector:selector];
}
But I receive warning: PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown. Why is this please?

Comment: @alexhajdu: Is `afterAnimation` a method defined on `target`?

Comment: @mipadi yes, it's a function defined on target (in uiviewcontroller)